# AngularJS Smarttable - event on select

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

Is there a way to trigger an event on row select in AngularJS Smart Table?

This was a subject in other thread but still no answer to this point.

[Unable to select the grid item using SmartTable in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584790/unable-to-select-the-grid-item-using-smarttable-in-angular-js/28041255?noredirect=1#comment44467128_28041255)

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/21

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed this functionality in order to show a panel whenever at least 1 row was selected. I originally set up a watch, but decided that was too expensive.

I ended up adding a callback inside the stSelectRow directive.

```
ng.module('smart-table')
  .directive('stSelectRow', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '^stTable',
      scope: {
          row: '=stSelectRow',
          callback: '&stSelected' // ADDED THIS
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        var mode = attr.stSelectMode || 'single';
        element.bind('click', function ($event) {
          scope.$apply(function () {
              ctrl.select(scope.row, mode, $event.shiftKey);
              scope.callback(); // AND THIS
          });
        });

        //***///
      }
    };
  });
```

I was then able to pass a function from my controller to the directive (note: you could pass the selected row back, I didn't need to)

```
tr ng-repeat="row in customerResultsTable" st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="multiple" st-selected="rowSelected()">
```

Referenced this post for help [Callback function inside directive attr defined in different attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896985/angular-js-callback-function-inside-directive-attr-defined-in-different-attr)

Comment: This could be a nice addition to the smart-table codebase?

Comment: @John yea should be a nice PR. thanks for this What-About-Bob

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy watch to place on a [Smart Table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/):

```
// fired when table rows are selected
$scope.$watch('displayedCollection', function(row) {

  if(!row) return;

  // get selected row
  row.filter(function(r) {
     if (r.isSelected) {
       console.log(r);
     }
  })
}, true);
```

related html:

```
<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection" class="select-table table">
```

[This github issue](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/7) was helpful.

Comment: this is working for me but gives error on page load of "Error: row is undefined smart-table". Do you have any suggestions how to fix that error? Thanks

Comment: @totallytotallyamazing no sorry, I have not been doing much Angular these days so can't help ya unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me!